# Partitioning Ubuntu to Install Windows

Tags: partitioning

I need some guidance with partitioning my machine which is running Ubuntu 11.10. I have try using gParted within Ubuntu, but I keep getting a root access error. Eventually, after a few hours of tinkering, I managed to get gParted to load. The problem now is that when i try to unmount HDD through gParted, in order to partition it, I am unable to do so. Help. :(

Answer (score 2):

If you are in ubuntu trying to unmount the system partition, you'll have trouble.

You need to do so through a livecd or liveusb - the one you used to install ubuntu has gparted. Boot with that to work with the install.

Be aware that once you have partitioned and installed windows you will need to reinstall grub.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling_GRUB2

Once you have resized the system partition to allow for windows I would check that the UUID has not changed.

Run the following command before and after you run gparted then compare the UUID's.

```
sudo blkid
```

If the partiton which has Ubuntu on has changed you will need to edit fstab.

Comment: The result was this:
/dev/sda1: UUID="28bf9d20-b732-423f-875c-01e4ecfcc1e8" TYPE="ext4"

Comment: How can i know if the partition has changed?

Comment: Run it again after the resize operation.